# Unit test in python: Conceptual question regarding dynamic typing / type hinting

Tags: python, unit-testing, dynamic-typing

Python is using dynamic typing. This makes me wonder, what I should actual test in unit test. Let's take a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(n, m):
    bar = np.multiply(n, m)
    return bar
```

I only want to allow integers in my calculation. But the function could also run with e.g. `float` numbers.

Following question/scenarios:

1. Which function arguments should I unittest? The amount of types is literally infinitive, should I test for all of those? E.g.

- Only test the intended result by using`int` as arguments?
- Also test the fails on using forbidden types e.g `float` as arguments
- If I also test the failure on forbidden types, which types should I actually test? Should I also check for e.g. `str` (which would let the `numpy.multiply` function fail)? Shall I just check for exemplary types that demonstrate that a type error is raised?
- If I check all of those types, should I then also explicitly allow only `int`?

e.g.

```
import numpy as np

def foo(n, m):
    if(not isinstance(n, int)):
        raise TypeError('Only int allowed')

    if(not isinstance(m, int)):
        raise TypeError('Only int allowed')

    bar = np.multiply(n, m)
    return bar
```

I can implement this in all functions I have, but it would bloat the code and spoil the concept of dynamic typing. Should I only implement it, where it is crucial?

2. If I only implement the type-check for functions, where it is crucial, what unit tests should I actually perform? Again, on all possible allowed types? In this case, if I also want to accept `float`, shall I also test it? But there might be data types I even don't know and still be working with this function, so how to I properly select the types to test?
3. What, if I use type hinting? Do the same checks inside the function and implement the same tests?

E.g.

```
import numpy as np

def foo(n: int, m: int) -> int:
    bar = np.multiply(n, m)
    return bar
```

- Can I restrict myself on testing for integers since type hinting "requires" no integers? Shall I still test if its failing for other data types (which one?)

Comment: The user may rely on dynamic typing, and delegate to the interpreter to stop at compile time for impossible operations. You may have to manually check some corner cases. I also though to use some meta-typing, since numpy float, for example, is not equal to native python float.